# How to load source files from Express server for use in HTML file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, network-programming

So I have recently started learning Node.js using Express and Socket.io, and am making a web app (a game.)

I have a `/public` folder that I am trying to use to serve the files the client will need from.
I'm used to defining what source files my page will need by doing it in the index.html file, using multiple `<script src=whateverpath></script>`'s.

How can I make the index.html get the source files it needs from the server?

I think what I am trying to do is to send the required files to the client, then 'store' them somehow and access them from the index.html using `<script src=path to wherever they are stored></script>`.

I don't feel the Express documentation explains stuff well enough for a beginner to understand.

Not really sure what I am meant to be asking for or looking for. I don't know what I don't know. =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your express based server side code, just put the source files used by client side including HTML, CSS, Javascript under your `/public` folder. then use the following code to let express serve it as static files (code from [express doc](http://expressjs.com/api.html)):

```
// GET /foo.js etc
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// GET /static/foo.js etc.
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

According to your `index.html`, use:

```
<script src="/foo.js"></script>
```

Or this if serving public folder over context `/static`:

```
<script src="/static/foo.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

On your server (usually server.js) you have to define what folder are you using for static content, eg:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

The you can access the files like always:

`<script src="/your_file_name.js"/>`